# Sumar minutos a fecha actual para obtener fecha en formato YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: java

Buenas,

No encuentro la forma de sumar minutos a la fecha actual y que me de una nueva fecha. Por ejemplo si le sumas 48 horas tendría que cambiar también el día, pero el código que tengo no lo hace. Estoy trabajando con lo siguiente:

```
java.util.Date fechaActual = new java.util.Date();
   try {
      String quedan = doc.select(".c-price .text-muted").first().text();
      String[] parts = quedan.split("•");
      String remaining = parts[1].replaceAll("\u00a0", "");
      String[] palabras = remaining.split(" ");

      boolean hay_dia = false;
      boolean hay_horas = false;
      boolean hay_minutos = false;
      for (String palabra : palabras) {
          if (palabra.equals("day")) {
             hay_dia = true;
          }

          if (palabra.equals("hour")) {
             hay_horas = true;
          }

          if (palabra.equals("minute")) {
             hay_minutos = true;
          }
       }

       int days = 0;
       int hours = 0;
       int minutes = 0;

       if (hay_dia && hay_horas && hay_minutos) {
          String[] dias = remaining.split("day");
          days = Integer.parseInt(dias[0]);

          String[] horas = dias[1].split("hour");
          hours = Integer.parseInt(horas[0]);

          String[] minutos = horas[1].split("minute");
          minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutos[0]);
       }

          if (hay_dia == false && hay_horas && hay_minutos) {

          String[] horas = remaining.split("hour");
          hours = Integer.parseInt(horas[0]);

          String[] minutos = horas[1].split("minute");
          minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutos[0]);
       }

          if (hay_dia == false && hay_horas == false && hay_minutos) {

              String[] minutos = remaining.split("minute");
              minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutos[0]);
          }

          if (hay_dia && hay_horas == false && hay_minutos == false) {
              String[] dias = remaining.split("day");
              days = Integer.parseInt(dias[0]);
          }

          if (hay_dia && hay_horas && hay_minutos == false) {
              String[] dias = remaining.split("day");
              days = Integer.parseInt(dias[0]);

              String[] horas = dias[1].split("hour");
              hours = Integer.parseInt(horas[0]);

           }


           Date nueva_fecha = sumarDiasAFecha(fechaActual, days, hours, minutes);

           Calendar fecha_calendar = DateToCalendar(nueva_fecha);
           int anyo = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
           int mes = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
           int dia = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
           int hour = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
           int minute = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

           String mes_fecha = "";
           if (mes < 10) {
              mes_fecha = "0"+mes;
           } else {
              mes_fecha = String.valueOf(mes);
           }

           String dia_fecha = "";
           if (dia < 10) {
              dia_fecha = "0"+dia;
           } else {
              dia_fecha = String.valueOf(dia);
           }

           String hour_fecha = "";
           if (hour < 10) {
              hour_fecha = "0"+hour;
           } else {
              hour_fecha = String.valueOf(hour);
           }

           String hour_minute = "";
           if (minute < 10) {
              hour_minute = "0"+minute;
           } else {
              hour_minute = String.valueOf(minute);
           }

           String fecha_total = String.valueOf(anyo) + "-" + mes_fecha + "-" + dia_fecha + " " + hour_fecha + ":" + hour_minute + ":00";

item.getValues().put(Constants.FECHA_SPOTLIGHT, fecha_total);
                                        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
      //SI LA OFERTA ES INDEFINIDA ENTONCES HAY QUE PONER FECHA NULA
                                                item.getValues().put(Constants.FECHA_SPOTLIGHT, "0000-00-00 00:00:00");
                                        }

public static Date sumarDiasAFecha(Date fecha, int dias, int horas, int minutos){
        if (dias==0 && horas==0 && minutos==0) return fecha;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(fecha); 

        //pasamos todo a minutos

        int total_minutos = (dias*24*60) + (60*horas) + minutos;

        //calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dias); 
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, total_minutos);
        return calendar.getTime(); 
    }

    public static Calendar DateToCalendar(Date date ) { 
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        return cal;
    }
```

Estoy intentando sumar por ejemplo 12 horas 48 minutos a la fecha actual y me devuelve `2017-05-22 01:11:00`, al menos el día debería ser 23 en vez de 22 (hora española).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conoces la clase Calendar de Java?

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(tuFechaBase); //tuFechaBase es un Date;
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutosASumar); //minutosASumar es int.
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR,   horasASumar); //horasASumar es int.
//lo que más quieras sumar
Date fechaSalida = calendar.getTime(); //Y ya tienes la fecha sumada.
```

Ahí tienes un ejemplito de como se usa.

Comment: Gracias, la estoy usando, pero algo debo de tener mal. Entiendo que se puede pasar todo a minutos y sumarlo, el resultado actualizará la fecha completamente.

Comment: Esta clase funciona correctamente y no deberías tener que configurar nada más, si no te funciona comprueba que los parametros que estás metiendo son los que tu crees. Asegurate de que estas asignaciones minutes = Integer.parseInt(minutos[0]);.. etc... estan funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes apoyarte en el calendario para sumar o restar valores a la fecha. Te adjunto una función que puedes utilizar:

```
private Date addMinutes(Date date, int amount){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, amount);

    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo mismo de la otra respuesta.

Comment: Es casi lo mismo que en la otra respuesta pero lo he añadido porque los comentarios me hacían entender que había algún problema de interpretación por parte de quien había formulado la pregunta. He considerado que el problema podía venir de alguna confusión con las variables que se utilizan que no han sido declaradas así como que se suman horas además de los minutos. Solo por eso me he tomado la molestia de incluirlo con una función que implemente únicamente esa funcionalidad.